# Copy data from one sheet to another when condition is met dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I would want to continuously loop through all the worksheet except for sheets named "Summary" & "Count" to extract data based on condition (If the cell value is "A", at D6). After that, it will copy certain cell values (Date at cell F3) and paste them onto the "Count" worksheet. The problem I am facing is I can't seem to paste the data I want to the "Count" worksheet.

Thank You! Any input/advice would be appreciated!

My code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim erow As Long

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case sh.Name

    Case Is = "Summary", "Count"

    Case Else
    If sh.[B10] = "Wash the whole vehicle" And sh.[D6].Value = "A" Then
        sh.[F3].Copy
        sh.Cells(11, 4).Copy

        sh("Count").Activate
        lastRowRpt = sh("Count").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        sh("Count").Range("A" & lastRowRpt + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If
End Select
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Change all instances of `sh("Count")` to `Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Count")`.  There are othr issues too, but that should get you started...

Answer (score 1):

`sh("Count")` isn't a valid syntax, while `Worksheets("Count")` is

other than that you don't need to `Select`/`Activate` anything but just go with fullly qualifed ranges

as follows:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, shCount As Worksheet ' add 'shCount' as a worksheet variable
Set shCount = Worksheets("Count") ' set 'shCount' variable to worksheet "Count"


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case sh.Name

        Case Is = "Summary", "Count"

        Case Else
            If sh.Range("D6").Value = "A" Then sh.Range("F3").Copy shCount.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

If your code is as above, I assume that the value paste to sheet `Count` is blank or other value than `Range("F3").

You have two copy code line.

```
sh.[F3].Copy
sh.Cells(11, 4).Copy
```

If you need to copy two value try to copy then paste for each. Or if you need to copy only range `F3` try to comment out the second copy line (`sh.Cells(11, 4).Copy`).

Comment: Please give me the reason.